# Laravel get method doesnt work like i wanted

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-8

i am trying to add data from form with get method but when i submit it, datas doesnt show up in the url like this

> addcustomers_token=vkmH0qnA6g2mfVcQzYUU3ZE0ZQvkQYs4DuCtKteX&company_name=Hebert+Frank+Inc&customer_name=Beau+Nixon&customer_surname=Schneider&customer_phone1=19655489736&customer_phone2=16612429699&customer_phone3=14871428281&customer_email1=qycuhuva%40mailinator.com&customer_score=2&customer_job=Doloribus+facilis+no&customer_gender=Woman&customer_source=Tawk+Canlı+Destek&user_id=1&user_company_id=1&tag_id=1&company_id=1

but its shows like that

> /addcustomers

my controller

```
 public function store(Request $req)
    {
        //
         // Form validation (Zorunlu Alanlar)
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'customer_phone1' => 'required',

     





           
        ]);

     

     
        $customers = new Customers;
       
        $customers->customer_name              = $req->input('customer_name');
        $customers->customer_surname           = $req->input('customer_surname');
        $customers->customer_phone1            = $req->input('customer_phone1');
      
        $customers->customer_phone2            = $req->input('customer_phone2');
      
        $customers->customer_phone3            = $req->input('customer_phone3');
        $customers->customer_email1            = $req->input('customer_email1');
        $customers->customer_score             = $req->input('customer_score');
        $customers->customer_job               = $req->input('customer_job');
        $customers->customer_gender            = $req->input('customer_gender');
        $customers->customer_source            = $req->input('customer_source');
        $customers->customer_ref               = "";
        $customers->company_id                 = $req->input('company_id');




        $customers->user_company_id            = $req->input('user_company_id');
        $customers->user_id                    = $req->input('user_id');
        $customers->tag_id                     = $req->input('tag_id');
        
        if(!empty($req->company_name)){
        $companies = new Companies;
        $companies->company_name              = $req->input('company_name');
        $companies->company_type              = "";
        $companies->company_address           = "";
        $companies->company_country           = "";
        $companies->company_city              = "";
        $companies->company_phone             = "";
        $companies->company_email             = "";
        $companies->company_tax_office        = "";
        $companies->company_tax_no            = "";
        $companies->company_website           = "";
        $companies->company_score             = "";
        $companies->company_status            = "";




        $companies->user_company_id         = "1";
        $companies->user_id                 = $req->input('user_id');
        $companies->tag_id                  = "1";
    

        $companies->updateTimestamps();
        $companies->save();}
     
        $customers->updateTimestamps();
        $customers->save();
 
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', true);
        }
```

related routes

```
Route::get('/addcustomers', function () {
    $companies = App\Models\Companies::all();  
    return view('addcustomers' , compact('companies'));
});

Route::get('/addcustomers2', [App\Http\Controllers\CustomersController::class, 'store']);
```

my form

```
 <form action="/add-customers2" method="GET">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Company Name </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" name="company_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name">
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Customer Name </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" name="customer_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Customer Surname </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" name="customer_surname" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Customer Surname">
                        </div>





                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong>Phone 1</strong> *</label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="11"
                                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"
                                name="customer_phone1" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" reqiured>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Phone 2 </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="11"
                                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"
                                name="customer_phone2" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Phone 3 </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" maxlength="11"
                                oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1');"
                                name="customer_phone3" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                        </div>







                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Customer Email </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" name="customer_email1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group  col-md-6 mb-4 ">

                            <label class="control-label" for="customer_score"> <strong> Customer Score
                                </strong></label>
                            <select class="form-control " name="customer_score">
                                <option  selected="true" disabled="disabled" hidden>Choose..</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>


                            </select>


                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Customer Job </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" name="customer_job" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Job">
                        </div>
                        <!-- 
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Call Later </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" name="call_later" class="form-control" placeholder="Call Later">
                        </div>

                        -->








                        <div class="form-group  col-md-6 mb-4 ">

                            <label class="control-label" for="customer_gender"> <strong> Customer Gender
                                </strong></label>
                            <select class="form-control select2" name="customer_gender">
                                <option value="Man" selected="selected">Man</option>
                                <option value="Woman">Woman</option>

                            </select>


                        </div>











                        <div class="form-group  col-md-12 mb-4 ">

                            <label class="control-label" for="customer_source"> <strong> Customer Source
                                </strong></label>
                            <select class="form-control " name="customer_source">
                                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled" hidden >Choose..</option>
                                <option value="Gelen Arama">Gelen Arama</option>
                                <option value="Tawk Canlı Destek">Tawk Canlı Destek</option>
                                <option value="WhatsApp">WhatsApp</option>
                                <option value="Formlar">Formlar</option>
                                <option value="E-Posta">E-Posta</option>
                                <option value="Referans">Referans</option>



                            </select>


                        </div>
                        <!-- 
                        <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                            <label> <strong> Customer Ref </strong></label>
                            <input type="text" name="customer_ref" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
                        </div>
                        -->

                        <?php $userId = Auth::id();  ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $userId; ?>">


                        <input type="hidden" name="user_company_id" class="form-control" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="tag_id" class="form-control" value="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="company_id" class="form-control" value="1">




















                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark mb-3 ">Kaydet</button>










                    </div>





                </form>
```

and i want to add records to database and redirect back to /addcustomers url

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Don't use GET. GET should be used for retrieving, not for adding. Especially for information like this. This should be a POST request.

Comment: @aynber so i cannot add data with get method ?

Comment: You *can*... but I wouldn't recommend it. POST is more secure

Comment: @aynber is my controller wrong what am i missing ? i cannot be able to add data with these codes.

Comment: @Emre You shouldn't use GET method as it has a limit to the length of the url. There is a risk that some of the data will be lost if it goes over 256 character (but it depends on the server). Using POST will send the data in the body of the request which has a way higher limit.

Comment: As of your issue, you have a redirect back once the insertion is done. Did you check your database to see if nothing is inserted ? Also, your validation can redirect you back. i suggest you start debugging and put some `dd()` in different places to see if the code reach those lines.

Comment: @N69S i checked the database, nothing inserted

Comment: @Emre GO for the `dd($req->all())` after validation, before the last return...and at each step of your code that you suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely why you see `/addcustomers` in the url is because after the submission you have:

```php
return redirect()->back()->with('success', true);
```

I suppose your blade/html form submission page is on `/addcustomers`, and after you submit it to `/addcustomers2` it redirects back to `/addcustomers` due to the above code. You can confirm this by opening the inspector on your browser and checking the networking tab (you might need to click an option to keep the history). There you will probably see the /addcustomers2 with all the parameters.

As others said you should use POST and rename your routes:

- GET /addcustomers -> GET /customers
- GET /addcustomers2 -> POST /customer

Comment: but i want to redirect same page not different page, and i want to see the datas in url.

Comment: You are not following convention of you want that. What happens if user hits reload? It would insert records in DB again if you don't redirect and parameters are in url.

Comment: If you really want that you can modify your code to not redirect back but return a view from your store function, then you will see that parameters in the url.